# change folder index to a HTML page within folder

Tags: html, path, directory

I have seen a few examples with `<a href=".">link to folder</a>` but i realy don't understant what it is or how to manipulate it or get it to set the specific html page within the folder.
My website is a basic one with only CSS and HTML
it is formatted as

```
[file]home.html // C:/Users/user/Desktop/mywebsite/home.html
[folder]Order // C:/Users/user/Desktop/mywebsite/order/
 ↳[file]ordersheet.html // C:/Users/user/Desktop/mywebsite/order/ordersheet.html
```

I want to try set the folder path  `C:/Users/user/Desktop/mywebsite/order/` as the file ordersheet.html `C:/Users/user/Desktop/mywebsite/order/ordersheet.html` how can this be done?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To set `/order` to `ordersheet.html` change the name of `ordersheet.html` to `index.html`

The `index.html` is the default file that the server will serve to the visitor when he visits that specific directory.

```
<a href="/Users/user/Desktop/mywebsite/order/">link text</a>
```

`link text` = what you want it to say to the user

`/Users/user/Desktop/mywebsite/order/` = directory path

Keep in mind that this will only work locally. If you have it up on a server, visitors don't have access to your full `C:/` drive so you have to use relative links, i.e. just `/order/`

Answer (score 0):

If I remebember correctly, you use something like this:

```
<a href="file:///C:/Users/user/Desktop/mywebsite/order/ordersheet.html>link to file on harddisk</a>
```

If you would want to have that anchor to a folder, you would just use this:

```
<a href="file:///C:/Users/user/Desktop/mywebsite/order/>link to a folder on harddisk</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your browser is operating directly on your system's local filesystem, so you can't.

What you have been looking at is a function of a **web server** (I'll use [Apache HTTPD](http://httpd.apache.org/) for examples here).

A typical configuration of a web server would map the local part of the URI onto a directory on the local file system and just serve up the files there if they matched the local part of the URI.

If the local part resolves to a directory (rather than a file) then it would look for a file in that directory with a name that matched [a list (typically including index.html)](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_dir.html) and serve up that file.

If none of the files on the list existed, then it would [generate an HTML document containing links to all the files in the directory](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_autoindex.html).

Since there is no web server involved when the browser is reading the local file system directly, there is no way to map the directory onto an index file, so you would need to explicitly include the filename in the URI (or switch to using a web server).